# How would you express an idiom "with this object, if it exists, do this" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Very often in Ruby (and Rails specifically) you have to check if something exists and then perform an action on it, for example:

```rb
if @objects.any?
  puts "We have these objects:"
  @objects.each { |o| puts "hello: #{o}"
end
```

This is as short as it gets and all is good, but what if you have `@objects.some_association.something.hit_database.process` instead of `@objects`? I would have to repeat it second time inside the `if` expression and what if I don't know the implementation details and the method calls are expensive?

The obvious choice is to create a variable and then test it and then process it, but then you have to come up with a variable name (ugh) and it will also hang around in memory until the end of the scope.

Why not something like this:

```rb
@objects.some_association.something.hit_database.process.with :any? do |objects|
    puts "We have these objects:"
    objects.each { ... }
end
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap)?

```
@objects.some_association.something.hit_database.process.tap do |objects|
  if objects.any?
    puts "We have these objects:"
    objects.each { ... }
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way so far without resorting to any external code. Would upvote more if I could.

Answer (score 3):

Note that there's no reason to check that an array has at least one element with `any?` if you're only going to send `each`, because sending `each` to an empty array is a no-op.

To answer your question, perhaps you are looking for https://github.com/raganwald/andand?

Comment: The reason to check with `any?` is to print the "We have these objects:" message before the objects themselves and not print anything if there aren't any. I really don't know any other way to do this. (looking at andand now)

Comment: i've just seen `ick` which might be more along the lines of what you want; their `let` is more similar to your `with` than `andand` is: http://ick.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, using a variable pollutes the namespace, but still, I think `if (var = value).predicate` is is a pretty common idiom and usually is perfectly ok:

```
if (objects = @objects.some_association.hit_database).present?
  puts "We have these objects: #{objects}"
end
```

Option 2: if you like to create your own abstractions in a declarative fashion, that's also possible using a block:

```
@objects.some_association.hit_database.as(:if => :present?) do |objects|
  puts "We have these objects: #{objects}"
end
```

Writing `Object#as(options = {})` is pretty straigthforward.

Comment: This would be perfect if it didn't pollute the scope.

Comment: Indeed, the first option pollutes the scope, which it's not nice (on the other hand, it allows to use the variable in other branches of the conditional). The `as` solution has not this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: If you're using Ruby 1.9, the [`Object#tap`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) method provides the same functionality as the code listed below.

It sounds like you just want to be able to save a reference to an object without polluting the scope, correct? How about we open up the `Object` class and add a method `do`, which will just yield itself to the block:

```
class Object
  def do
    yield self if block_given?
    return self # allow chaining
  end
end
```

We can then call, for example:

```
[1,2,3].do { |a| puts a.length if a.any? }
=> 3
[].do { |a| puts a.length if a.any? }
=> nil
```

Comment: There's already the `Object#tap` method which can be used for that.

Comment: Ah, then cross my answer out and just put a reference to that. :) Forgot that was included by default in Ruby 1.9 now.

Comment: Yes, this is already better. I can now do: `lots.of.methods.tap { |o| if o.any?; puts "hello"; o.each { ... }; end }`